# NuGet package installed on the solution level instead of project level

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to customize an existing NuGet package to add some new behavior, specifically into a package called StyleCop.MsBuild

1. Downloaded the source of the package from bitbucket repo (https://bitbucket.org/adamralph/stylecop-msbuild/wiki/Home)
2. Changed id of package in *.nuspec file from StyleCop.MSBuild to *MyCustomPackage*
3. Created *.nupkg file using NuGet Package Explorer
4. Uploaded *.nupkg file to my local NuGet server

So the only change was the **id** of the original package.

But now when I try to install *MyCustomPackage* into a project, it is installed on the solution level and not on the project level. Visual Studio creates a folder called '.nuget' in the root of the solution and places the packages.config file in there.

Not sure what causes this change since all I did was to change the package id.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StyleCop.MsBuild package has an msbuild target in the build folder and the convention is that the name should match the package id. So by changing the package id, the msbuild target file was not referenced anymore and the package became a solution level one.

https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package#import-msbuild-targets-and-props-files-into-project